# How can I pause an async function and prompt user a question, then conditionally continue based on answer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynccallback

I am trying to reduce the logic in my React UI components. I have a multi step process where I need to ask questions and based on the answer conditionally proceed with the process.

The flow looks like this:

1. User calls function
2. Function checks wether action is approved or not
3. If action is permanently approved continue to step 7
4. If action is not approved, prompt user with question wether to approve permanently or only this one time
5. Wait for user to answer question
6. Proceed with permanent approval or one-time approval
7. Fetch data, calculate stuff
8. Pause again and ask user if calculations are correct
9. If user confirms finish process and return result

I think I have to use callbacks, but not sure how to pause and pass the answer back to the parent function to continue.

A high level overview or the keywords for what to google would help me a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to pause it? That seems like a bad design - why not splitting it up into different parts?

Comment: You dont do all that with a single function, it's many functions conditionally chained together.

Comment: Why don't you just create one state like const [step, setStep] = (1) and depending on that do some stuff and later on change this state, show different elements or do another task

Comment: Thanks, guys. I think I was already on the right track and for some reason thought I needed to do it different. You just confirmed my current approach - thanks!